# Symfony and CSS cache in multitenant SaaS (a CSS for each tenant)

Tags: css, symfony, caching, multi-tenant, saas

I have a symfony App (SaaS, multitenant) and I'm looking a good solution for managing CSS Styles.

I have a general CSS theme, but, for each tenant I want to create a individual CSS (i.e., custom color links, buttons, etc...).

I have the config files arrangeds by folders (each tenant, one folder) like this:

```
app
--config
---tenantA
-----config.yml
---tenantB
-----config.yml
...
```

In the config file, I have a twig global called css_app. For example:

```
· TenantA -> config.yml -> app_css: tenantA.css
· TenantB -> config.yml -> app_css: tenantB.css
```

Then, in block style Sheets, I call the tenant CSS:

```
{% set cssload = "css/" ~ app_css  ~ ".css" %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/{{cssload}}">
```

And it returns (i.e):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/tenantA.css">
```

The problem is the caché. If I open de app by tenantB, it returns the tenantA.css. Only returns the correct CSS if I clear the caché...

There are a good practice for this? It's possible set don't cach CSS files?

Comment: If the css file name being loaded doesn't change it's the configuration that got cached into container,not the CSS file itself. Question is how are you loading tenant's configuration?

Comment: @malarzm   I! I solved the CSS problem arranging the cache in folders by clients. In KernelApp by getCacheDir:

return $this->rootDir . '/cache/' . $tenant. '/' . $this->environment.

I'm loading the tenants configurations by AppKernel too (in 
registerContainerConfiguration function):

$loader->load($this->getRootDir().'/config/'.$tenant.'/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');

The configuration files are arranged like the folders described in the original question.